# Reduce a Space between unicode '\u2261' in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How to reduce the space or no space between Unicode **"\u2261"**. I need to print "\u2261" continuously, without space. Try the following things, but in all cases, there is some blank space between two characters.

```
print('\u2261'+'\u2261')
print('\u2261'*3)
print('\u2261'*3,sep="")

list =['\u2261','\u2261','\u2261']
str =""
str2 = str.join(list)
print(str2)
```

Comment: I don't see spaces but I do see line returns between the print statements. Maybe post an image or formatted code with your output?

Comment: @CaptainCaveman - You didn't see spaces between the three characters in `print('\u2261'*3,sep="")`? That would suggest your font is different than mine. I saw a distinct space between characters.

Comment: I think this is about eliminating the inter character gap and choosing a font that makes this as wide as possible. So, in pyqt5 you'd be looking at spacing control in whatever widget you are using. In a console, like the print statement you show, you may not be able to

Comment: [QFont.setLetterSpacing](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfont.html#setLetterSpacing).

Comment: @ekhumoro, Thank-you . Using  as per your suggestion,  set letter spacing, workedout